# Kubernetes service name resolution not working

Tags: angular, kubernetes, webpack, service, coredns

I have 2 angular applications, they are in different pods in the same (default) namespace on a Minikube cluster. I am using module-federation for communication between them.

My yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: host-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: host-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: host-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: host-app
          image: testexampleuser/host-mf-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

---
 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: host-app-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: host-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: remote-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: remote-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: remote-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: remote-app
          image: testexampleuser/remote-mf-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: remote-app-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: remote-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ms.test
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: host-app-srv
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /todo-list
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: host-app-srv
                port:
                  number: 80
```

and my webpack.config.js for the main app:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "hostApp",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "hostApp",
      remotes: {
        remoteApp1: 'remoteApp1@http://remote-app-srv/remoteEntry.js'
      },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

In this I am specifying my url as http://remote-app-srv/remoteEntry.js, so trying to access it through the service name, but I have `GET http://remote-app-srv/remoteEntry.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` in the console, which is saying that it is not able to find the IP based on the service name. The same thing happens when using the fully qualified name for the service. However when using `kubectl exec -it remote-app-64b485f7d8-pph7z -- nslookup remote-app-srv` in the command prompt, I get

```
kubectl exec -it remote-app-64b485f7d8-pph7z -- nslookup remote-app-srv
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Name:   remote-app-srv.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.99.114.182

** server can't find remote-app-srv.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find remote-app-srv.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN

** server can't find remote-app-srv.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN


** server can't find remote-app-srv.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN

command terminated with exit code 1
```

So it seems, that it is resolving correctly, but when using the service name in the app, it is not able to find the IP for that. What can be the cause of this issue?

**Update**

When I modify my ingress and include the /remoteEntry.js as a path, which then forwards to my remote-service, and modify my url as: http://ms.test/remoteEntry.js then in the console I have:

```
remoteEntry.js:1     GET http://ms.test/487.a4d1c1bd4d8ce404.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
__webpack_require__.l @ remoteEntry.js:1
__webpack_require__.f.j @ remoteEntry.js:1
(anonymous) @ remoteEntry.js:1
__webpack_require__.e @ remoteEntry.js:1
./TodoListModule @ remoteEntry.js:1
g @ remoteEntry.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
T @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
g @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
e @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
F @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
q @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
T @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
g @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
onInvoke @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
run @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
onInvokeTask @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
runTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
y @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
U @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
W @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
ue @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
load (async)
e @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
scheduleTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
scheduleEventTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
o.set @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
e @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
T @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
g @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
e @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
A @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
O @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
T @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
g @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
e @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
I @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
D @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
T @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
g @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
e @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
P @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
Y @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
loadChildren @ 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1
loadModuleFactoryOrRoutes @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
loadChildren @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
Z @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
x @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
_trySubscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
X @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
X @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
e.subscribe.s @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
_trySubscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
Z @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
x @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
_trySubscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
X @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
Z @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
x @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
_trySubscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
X @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
F @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
e.subscribe.s @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
subscribe.i @ 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1
F._next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
next @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
(anonymous) @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
onInvoke @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
run @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
onInvokeTask @ 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
runTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
y @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
invokeTask @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
U @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
W @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
ue @ polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1
268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 487 failed.
(error: http://ms.test/487.a4d1c1bd4d8ce404.js)
    at __webpack_require__.f.j (remoteEntry.js:1:7277)
    at remoteEntry.js:1:1216
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (remoteEntry.js:1:1177)
    at ./TodoListModule (remoteEntry.js:1:83)
    at Object.g (remoteEntry.js:1:143)
    at 268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1:528
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at T (268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1:163)
    at g (268.4135e908b4fc6bc1.js:1:365)
256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')
    at Xe (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:31475)
    at new Xa (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:136284)
    at Xo.create (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:136822)
    at 384.caca277fba7706c5.js:1:79337
    at 256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:10630
    at F._next (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:10079)
    at F.next (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:3860)
    at Z.subscribe._ (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:11217)
    at F._next (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:10079)
    at F.next (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:3860)
    at ye (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:16009)
    at ye (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:15548)
    at polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:16854
    at N.invokeTask (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:7153)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (256.612799c9aae468e4.js:1:170779)
    at N.invokeTask (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:7074)
    at z.runTask (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:2495)
    at y (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:9194)
    at P.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:8237)
    at U (polyfills.fe9dcec8806eea43.js:1:20912)
```

Which I find strange, because when I enter inside the pod, I can clearly see, that the file is available, moreover, I am even able to reach the content of http://ms.test/remoteEntry.js in the browser, it just not works when using in the app.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `Ingress`, you should not use service for accessing your app. First you need to resolv the `ms.test` to your minikube ip, then try the paths you set in your Ingress yaml file. For example you should try this :

```
GET http://ms.test/
```

when you hit the `/` path it will call the `host-app-srv`.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I already tried that, but when using http://ms.test/remoteEntry.js as my url, I see GET http://ms.test/remoteEntry.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), which is true, because I didn't specify /remoteEntry.js in my ingress, but since this endpoint is provided by the module-federation plugin I don't think I should include it in my ingress.

Comment: How do you handle the communication between the host app and remote app?
I mean when you run your app locally, is it OK?

Comment: Yes, that way it is working fine. Even when I change my service types to nodeport and specify my url in http://minikube-ip:node-port format, it still works. It is just not the preferred solution, because it basically ignores the ingress, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I think found your answer. I installed minikube and i tried your yaml files. The problem is you didn't enable ingress addon on minikube. First try `minikube addons enable ingress` then try again! . It's actually because of ingress controller. Hope it helps!

Comment: I did, and able to see the apps start up correctly. If setting / to navigate to either host or remote, they work seperately, they are just not able to communicate

Comment: Could explain more about your code? It's confusing for me. I have 2 questions:
When the remote-app been called?
What is the relation between host and remote?
Thanks.